# Sum up prices on selecting options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show the total price to the customer by each option that's selected:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
    var org = parseInt($('span#totalprice').text());
    var chk = parseInt($(this).attr('price'));
    total = this.checked ? (org + chk) : (org - chk);
    $('span#totalprice').html(total);
});
```

It works, when check or uncheck the check boxes, total price will change. But the problem is if the submitted form has some validation errors on some inputs, the same page loads with given errors & all inputs that user entered before (check boxes too) but total price will not change since I'm using `.change` method.

As I'm not much familiar with related methods, Is there any method which will calculate total price on page ready and on input change?

Comment: You probably need to explain how you validate data etc.. Your question is a bit unclear, we need to know more about your code and solutions you've used.

Comment: @MMM Inputs are validated by PHP, so it's server side and on page reload the total price will reset however options are checked.

Comment: So you simply want to trigger the calculation code on page load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to simulate the change event like that :

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
    var org = parseInt($('span#totalprice').text());
    var chk = parseInt($(this).attr('price'));
    total = this.checked ? (org + chk) : (org - chk);
    $('span#totalprice').html(total);
}).trigger('change');
```

---

## Edit

Since you want when atleast one is selected, use this instead :

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
    var org = parseInt($('span#totalprice').text());
    var chk = parseInt($(this).attr('price'));
    total = this.checked ? (org + chk) : (org - chk);
    $('span#totalprice').html(total);
}).filter(':checked').trigger('change');
```

`.filter(':checked')` should return nothing, therefor it will not trigger anything.

Comment: When page loads for the first time, because no option is checked, the price is negative!

Answer (score 0):

what about to recalculate every time the whole bunch of items?

e.g. create the function

```
function sumup_everything() {
  var sum = 0;

  $('input[type=checkbox]').each(/* here you calculate */);

  /* setup sum value */
}
```

Then call it on input change and document.ready.

```
$(function() {
  $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){ sumup_everything() });

  sumup_everything();
});
```